# SyntaxError for SCSS in Vue Jest

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass, jestjs

I'm trying to import and mount a component in Jest. Unfortunately, I'm facing an error stating

```
styles/variables.scss:2
$blue:#324157;
      ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Here are the solutions that didn't work for me.

**Using identity-obj-proxy** (DIDN'T WORK):

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "\\.(css|scss|sass|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
}
```

**Using styleMock** (DIDN'T WORK):

```
//package.json
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "\\.(css|scss|sass|less)$": "<rootDir>/tests/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
}

//<rootDir>/tests/__mocks__/styleMock.js
module.exports = {}
```

The following solutions doesn't work and the error still persists.

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution which may help others by simply adding `jest-transform-stub` in `jest.transform`

```
"jest": {
  "transform": {
    ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "jest-transform-stub"
  }
}
```

Source: [vuejs/vue-test-utils-jest-example/issues/11](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils-jest-example/issues/11)

Comment: You can also use `vue-jest` as the transformer.